# Reading data as an object and inputing into an Object array

Tags: java, file-io

The overarching theme of this project is to sort stuff. My full code works (sort of) but the issue is that it always sorts my data as a String and I am pretty sure its caused by that fact that I am reading the dataFile's line as a String and inputting that into the array as a string.

```
Object[] list = new Object[n];

    if (n > 0) {

        try {
            BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataFile.txt"));

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                String t = file.readLine();
                if (t != null)
                    list[i] = t;
            }
            file.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error accessing file.");
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("There was an error reading from the file.");
        }
    }
```

If someone could point me in the correct direction on how to read a line and input it into an array as an Object, I would be grateful.

Comment: `file.readLine()` will never returns `null`. It returns `empty string`.

Answer (score 0):

> **A Java String is an Object**. (String extends Object)
>   So *you can get an Object reference via assignment*!

Perhaps, you can try adding content from your file to an Object array like below:-

```
Object[] list = new Object[n];

    if (n > 0) {

        try {
            BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataFile.txt"));

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                String t = file.readLine();
                Object obj = t;  
                if (obj != null)
                    list[i] = obj;
            }
            file.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error accessing file.");
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("There was an error reading from the file.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that is not actually functionally different from what op did.

Comment: The casted obj didn't work, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Java8 internal tools to ready text files:

```
public static Object[] readAllLinesFromFile(Path path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(path).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the Java8 internal tools but thanks for your suggestion, maybe I'll look it up!

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the issue. This code fixes, thanks to the people who helped.

```
void dataType() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            try {
                checkINT = Integer.parseInt((String) list[i]);
                list[i] = checkINT;
            } catch (Exception eInt) {
                try { 
                    checkDBL = Double.parseDouble((String) list[i]);
                    list[i] = checkDBL;
                } catch (Exception eDbl) {
                    // Then its a string.
            }
        }
    }
}
```